# Null reference error in asp.net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I am using following line in my asp.net MVC 3 view.

```
@Model.AuthorizedAgent.Person.FirstName
```

But I am getting error because AuthorizedAgent is null. How can I avoid this error ?

Comment: Easy, make sure AuthorizedAgent is not null.  For any more help than that you're going to need to show us more code. :)

Comment: What If I want to provide alternate text if some value is null ?

Comment: I would create a viewmodel with a property named firstname and then set the property in the controller according if the value is null or not to avoid putting logic in your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a view model with the following property:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.AuthorizedAgentFirstName)
```

and then have the controller perform the necessary tests and populate the property accordingly:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    SomeModel model = ...
    SomeViewModel vm = new SomeViewModel();

    // TODO: refactor this part to a mapping layer. AutoMapper is 
    // a good tool for the job
    if (model.AuthorizedAgent != null && model.AuthorizedAgent.Person != null)
    {
        vm.AuthorizedAgentFirstName = model.AuthorizedAgent.Person.FirstName;
    }
    return View(vm);
}
```

And in order to provide an alternate text of the value is null you could use the `DisplayFormat` attribute:

```
[DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "EMPTY")]
public string AuthorizedAgentFirstName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here. The first is to ensure the model has a value. Without seeing your code, I have no clue whether this should always have a value or not. The other option is conditionally grabbing the value, which you can do easily in both ASP.NET and Razor view engines.